# Display unique values & count of a data-frame side by side in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I know how to display the number of unique values in a column & the count of the number of columns, but I want to know if there is a way to display this information side by side?

That is, I want to know if there is a way to also display the number of columns **(1338)** next to the values `47, 2, 548, 6, ...` respectively.

I.e. how do you output this number next to each of the **nunique** values.

It may seem unnecessary/redundant, but I would like to know if this is possible.

> **Current code & output:**

[image]

> **Desired output (or something similar):**

[image]

Comment: Can you put in writing your desired output?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski see desired output above.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html can help a bit here.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
dataframe.groupby('name of key').count()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"a": [3,5,4,3,6,5,4,3,7,1], "b": list("aaabccaabb"), "c": list("pqqqpppqqq")})

df.agg(["nunique", "count"]).T
```

Outputs:

```py
   nunique  count
a        6     10
b        3     10
c        2     10
```

**Edit**

To add name to an index:

```py
df2=df.agg(["nunique", "count"]).T.reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "column"})
```

Outputs:

```py
  column  nunique  count
0      a        6     10
1      b        3     10
2      c        2     10
```

Comment: This did what I was looking for. Where can I find more info on this function and how it works?

Comment: Also, in your code, is there a way to display "column" above the column titles "a", "b", and "c"?

Comment: Try: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html. And https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html and generally getting familiar with ```numpy``` and its capabilities will also help ;)

Comment: Yup - try: ```df2=df.agg(["nunique", "count"]).T
df2.index.name="column"```

Comment: Hmm, the display is a little off. In that case I might not use it.

Comment: You can try then ```df2=df2.reset_index()``` (not sure what's the precise view you're going after)

Comment: I prefer to have consistent formatting. Would like to have "column" displayed on the same line as "nunique" and "count".